# Why is login failing for Apache FTPSClient?

Tags: java, authentication, apache-commons, ftp-client, ftps

I am trying to connect to an FTPS site using Apache Commons FTPSClient like so....

```
def ftpsClient = new FTPSClient()

ftpsClient.connect('9.14.113.212')

def reply = ftpsClient.getReplyCode();

println "Reply is $reply"

println "Login is ${ftpClient.login(username, password)}"
```

The reply code I get back is 234 but login returns false. I am sure the username and password are correct because it works when I try to connect over an FTPS client like Cyberduck.

Is there any way to see why the login is failing here? As suggested in the [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html), I set the the JVM property -Djavax.net.debug=all but it didn't reveal anything. The handshake seems to occur without issues.

Comment: Does your server allow ftp ssh?

Comment: @FreedomPride, I thought ftp ssh was SFTP whereas this is FTPS, two different protocols, correct me if I am wrong.